# A stuck in Theorem 8.2 of Baby Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

The following is Rudin's Theorem $8.2$ and its proof.
[image]

The proof seems a bit hard for readers like me. So, I have tried an approach to its proof using partial sums and applying Theorem $7.8$ & Theorem $7.12$ as follows.

**Proof**

Consider a sequence $\left\{s_n\right\}$ of partial sums $s_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_i\ x^i}$, where $\left|x\right|<1$ and where $\sum {c_n}$ converges.

Since  $\sum\ c_n$ converges, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\sum_{i=m}^{n}\left|{c_i}\right|<\varepsilon$ if $m,n>N$.

Then,

$\left|s_n\left(x\right)-s_m\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_ix^i}-\sum_{i=0}^{m}{c_ix^i}\right|$
$$= \left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i x^i\right|\le\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}\left|c_i\right|\le\sum_{i=m}^{n}\left|c_i\right|<\varepsilon,\  \text{if}\ m,n>N.$$
Thus, by Theorem $7.8$, Cauchy-criterion, ${s_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ given by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n\ x^n\ }$.

Since $s_n$ is the sum of a finite number of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$, $s_n$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, too.

Then, by Theorem $7.12$, the limit function $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$.
Then, we obtain

$$\lim_{x→1}\;f(x)=\lim_{x→1}⁡∑_{n=0}^∞\;c_n x^n =∑_{n=0}^∞c_n .$$

\qed

I am wondering if my attempt is valid or not and is it isn't please suggest me. Thanks.

The following are the theorems I used in my attempt.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your application of 7.10 assume $\sum |c_n|$ converges? ... Also, continuity of $f$ on $(-1,1)$ isn't enough.  You need continuity from the left at $x=1$.

Comment: @Brian Moehring, I don't think the continuity from the right is needed, for the function $f$ is defined only in $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: For the record, the second issue is mostly cosmetic.  The main issue that you really cannot overcome with your proof is it assumes absolute convergence of $\sum c_n$, and for most purposes, 8.2 really only is interesting in the case the series of coefficients is convergent and _not_ absolutely convergent.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I have corrected the existing error, thanks.

Comment: The inequality $|c_n x^n| \leq c_n$ is now false unless $c_n \geq 0$, which along with $\sum c_n$ being convergent, is now even stronger than the assumption $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try my best.

Comment: It's a bit of a moving target, as both my comments and answer are now seemingly unrelated to the question.  Anyway, your current "fix" doesn't work either, as this step is invalid: $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_ix^i}-\sum_{i=0}^{m}{c_ix^i}\right|\le\left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i\right|$$  For any future attempts: if your proof is strong enough to show the power series converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$ then it's invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has two issues:

- In your application of 7.10, you've assumed $\sum c_n$ converges **absolutely**.
- In your final steps, you've only written that $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$, which in no way justifies the evaluation of the limit as $x \to 1$.

Of these, the former is devastating and the latter is mostly cosmetic.

That is, dealing with them in reverse:

- Your applications of 7.10 and 7.12 could have just used $E = [-1,1]$ instead of $E = (-1,1)$.  With this change, you would be able to conclude from $f$ being continuous on $[-1,1]$ that the limit $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = f(1)$, which would be exactly what you wanted to show, if not for the fact...
- Theorem 8.2 only assumes $\sum c_n$ converges, not that it converges absolutely.  With this, your initial application of 7.10 is invalid.

The good news is that your proof can be immediately modified to prove the corollary of 8.2 which is identical to 8.2 except that we strengthen the assumption to $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely.  The bad news is that this weakening of 8.2 is much less useful, and obviously it fails to provide an alternative proof of 8.2 itself.

Comment: I have corrected the existing errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the proof of Theorem 8.2 in which some modifications are added to the original one in order for the reader like me to see.

Proof:
Let $ s_n=c_0+\dots+c_n,\ \ s_(-1)=0.$ Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}{c_nx^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}{\left(s_n-s_{n-1}\right)x^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}{s_nx^n}-x\sum_{n=0}^{m}{s_{n-1}x}^{n-1}=\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}{s_nx^n}+s_mx^m-s_{-1}=\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}{s_nx^n}+s_mx^m.$$
For $\left|x\right|<1$, we let $m\rightarrow\infty$ and obtain

(9) $f\left(x\right)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{m}{c_nx^n}}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}{\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}{s_nx^n}}=\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{s_nx^n}.$
Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{s_n}=\sum\ c_n$ converges, suppose $s=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{s_n}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N$ so that $n>N$ implies
$$\left|s-s_n\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Then, since
$$\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\left(1-x\right)\times\frac{1}{1-x}=1,$$
we obtain from (9)
$$
\left|f\left(x\right)-s\right|=\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{s_nx^n}-\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^ns\right|=\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(s_n-s)x^n}\right|\le\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\left(s_n-s\right)x^n}\right|+\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}{\left(s_n-s\right)x^n}\right|<\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\left(s_n-s\right)x^n}\right|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\ \left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=N+1}^{N}x^n\right|\le\left|\left(1-x\right)\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\left(s_n-s\right)x^n}\right|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
If $x>1-\delta$, for some suitably so chosen $\delta$ that $\delta\ \left|\sum_{n=0}^{N}{\left(s_n-s\right)x^n}\right|\le\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, we get
$$\left|f\left(x\right)-s\right|\le\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$
Note that $x>1-\delta$ and $|x|<1$ means $|1-x|<\delta$.
Thus, it follows that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\left|1-x\right|<\delta\Rightarrow\left|f\left(x\right)-s\right|\le\varepsilon.$

Thus, we conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{f(x)}=s=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

In the following proof I have used Theorem 7.11 instead of Theorem 7.12.

**Proof**

Consider a sequence $\left\{s_n\right\}$ of partial sums $s_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_i\ x^i}$, where $\left|x\right|<1$ and where $\sum {c_n}$ converges.

Since  $\sum\ c_n$ converges, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\sum_{i=m}^{n}\left|{c_i}\right|<\varepsilon$ if $m,n>N$.

Then,

$\left|s_n\left(x\right)-s_m\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_ix^i}-\sum_{i=0}^{m}{c_ix^i}\right|$
$$= \left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i x^i\right|\le\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}\left|c_i\right|\le\sum_{i=m}^{n}\left|c_i\right|<\varepsilon,\  \text{if}\ m,n>N.$$
Thus, by Theorem $7.8$, Cauchy-criterion, ${s_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ given by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n\ x^n\ }$.

Since $1$ is a limit point of $(-1,1)$ and $\lim_{x→1}\;⁡s_n (x)=∑_{i=0}^n\;c_i =A_n$, then, by theorem $7.11$, ${A_n}$ converges and
$$\lim_{x→1}⁡f(x)=\lim_{n→∞}\;A_n=\sum_{n=0}^∞\;c_n .$$

\qed

The following is Theorem 7.11

[image]

Comment: This isn't necessarily true: $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_ix^i}-\sum_{i=0}^{m}{c_ix^i}\right|\le\left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i\right|$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake again. Now, I have fixed the error. Thanks. $$$$ Though, your comments seem irrelevant, I'd love to leave them as they are as the records.

Comment: That didn't fix it.  Again, $$\left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i x^i\right|\le\left|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}c_i\right|$$ may be false.

Comment: You may be aware of this, but your most recent edit brings us full circle back to assuming $\sum c_i$ converges absolutely, which is problematic for the reasons in my answer.

Comment: I don’nt think $\sum c_n$ need to be convergent absolutely so that $\sum_{i=m}^{n}\left|c_i\right|<\varepsilon$ because it is just a consequence of convergence.

Indeed, by Theorem 3.22, we can show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\left|c_n\right|<\varepsilon$ for $n\ge N$ for some integer $N$ if $\sum c_n$ converges. Moreover, Theorem 3.23 says that if $\sum c_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0$.

Comment: Note that no argument you said there had to do with $\sum_{i=m}^n |c_i|$ because none of them apply to that situation.  The condition that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that $N \leq m < n$ implies $\sum_{i=m}^n |c_i| < \varepsilon$ is **literally the definition** of $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|$ being a Cauchy sequence.  As $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, it's equivalent to $\sum |c_i|$ converging (i.e. the definition of $\sum c_i$ being absolutely convergent).

Comment: If it helps, consider $$c_i = \frac{(-1)^i}{i+1}$$ The series $\sum c_i$ converges but $\sum |c_i|$ diverges.  Run through your arguments with it. (Then ask yourself which theorem in PMA you would use to evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i$)

Comment: But we are now considering the Cauchy criterion for the sequence of functions not for that of the numbers. Thanks.